# Displaying random pixels on LCD

Tags: display, lcd, pixels

Will it damage my LCD screen if I display a stream of continuously changing randomly colored pixels, at the monitor's refresh rate, for a long time? As in, will it damage it any more than displaying a more coherent image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not, as far as I can tell. If anything, the **opposite** of this (displaying a static image) is more harmful to displays: this is called [screen burn-in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_burn-in).

[image: screen burn-in example] (from that Wikipedia article)